# Limit concurrent sessions per user in WSO2IS

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 IS as our enterprise identity platform. One of our tenants must restrict the number of concurrent sessions per user for security reasons.
The expected behaviour is the following: when a user logs in, if he/she already has logged in previously and the session is still valid, the new session must overwrite the previous one, so the login ends ok and he/she gets logged out from the first device/browser. Summing up: the new session always invalidates the old one.
I've been researching sites like this or http://soasecurity.org/ searching for answers, but I couldn't find any.
I think that I need to store the WSO2 IS session id (the one that comes in the commonauthId cookie and gets stored in session cache/persistence store) in the user store, so I can check what's the current user session and log out the user if the cookie id and the store id don't match. But there are two main concerns:

- Where do I store the user session id? My main user store is LDAP, but I'd like to avoid one extra attribute there, because it's shared with many other applications and promote changes like this could be difficult for many reasons. Is there any way to put this data into a secondary store?
- What's the most appropiate extension point in WSO2 IS to add code for storing the session id in a user store? I've been looking through the authentication framework and found that the method concludeFlow in DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler class is where new sessions are created when there isn't a previously cached one available. It seems a bit "tricky" to extend that method, but I couldn't find a better solution. Maybe you can customize the authenticator or the user store, but I think that's not a good point of extension inside the authentication flow, because the new sessions are created later, in the request handler.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of WSO2 IS are you using?

Comment: The last stable release: 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The WSO2 identity server actually doesn't care about the number of open sessions. IMHO the identity server is not the best enforcement point where to check for the open sessions. Once the user is already logged in, you don't have much control over the framework and the user assertions (or an Oauth token) are returned.

> Where do I store the user session id?

If you [enable the session persistence](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Enabling+Authentication+Session+Persistence), the session information (user session, saml SP sessions, ...) are stored in the database. However - it is intended for internal use. If the user logs out or closes the browser, the records may be still there. There's no information about the user web session.

Just a hint - we've used a VPN proxy (Juniper SA as SP) and WSO2IS as IdP to enforce a unique user session (for a new session the old one is invalidated).

Have fun